# google places api use custom marker icons based on restaurant cuisine

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I'm trying to use different marker icons for the different types of cuisine for restaurants generated from the nearbySearch in google places.

As an example if a restaurant is a pizzeria it should display a custom pizzeria icon(that i have stored locally) or if a restaurant is a burger place, it should display a burger icon instead of the default restaurant icon.

As far as I have searched there is only the possibility to use custom icons for the type of the place(e.g. "restaurant", "library", "parking"...) and I can't find a way to get the subtypes of restaurant type. Is there a way to work around this problem?

Here is an example code of the search and callback function that really draw the markers:

```
     var MARKER_PATH =
    "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/images/marker_green";
unction search() {
  var search = {
    bounds: map.getBounds(),
    types: ["restaurant"]
  };

  places.nearbySearch(search, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    document.getElementById("lat").value = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
    document.getElementById("lng").value = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
      // Create a marker for each restaurant found, and
      // assign a letter of the alphabetic to each marker icon.
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        var markerLetter = String.fromCharCode("A".charCodeAt(0) + i % 26);
        var markerIcon = MARKER_PATH + markerLetter + ".png";
        // Use marker animation to drop the icons incrementally on the map.
        markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: results[i].geometry.location,
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
          icon: markerIcon
        });
        // If the user clicks a restaurant marker, show the details of that restaurant
        // in an info window.
        markers[i].placeResult = results[i];
        google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], "click", showInfoWindow);
        setTimeout(dropMarker(i), i * 100);
        addResult(results[i], i);
      }
    }
  }
```

My idea was to get the cuisine type by using the keyword property of the generated results, something like this(just two cuisine types for example):

```
if (results[i].keyword === "pizzaria") {
          markerIcon = "img/icons/pizzaria.png";
        } else if (results[i].keyword === "burger") {
          markerIcon = "img/icons/fastfood.png";
        }
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work and I steel wonder if there is a way to solve it..

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not try to find some "pizzeria" as specified by [this](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types?hl=fr) article of the google's documentation.

However, you can consult the [`types`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places?hl=fr#place_search_requests) (like keywords) of the restaurants and try to find "pizzeria" in them:

```
if (results[i].name.indexOf ("pizzeria") || results[i].name.indexOf ("pizza hut") /*...*/) {
          markerIcon = "img/icons/pizzaria.png";
        } else if (results[i].name.indexOf ("burger")) {
          markerIcon = "img/icons/fastfood.png";
        }
```

*Tell me if you have some question.*

*Good luck.*

*Sphinx*

Answer (score 0):

You would need more details about each place than it is currently available.

The Places API exposes all restaurants with "restaurant" in its `types` field, you would need additional, more detailed types like as "hamburger_restaurant" or "italian_restaurant", as they show up in Google Maps ([example](https://www.google.ch/maps/place/Holy+Cow!/@47.375455,8.5425704,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x479aa0a86cf41099:0xf2784d9b380683e8!8m2!3d47.375455!4d8.5447644?hl=en)). This is a feature request you can subscribe to:

[35822953](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35822953): Detailed / primary place types (as seen on Google Maps)